# MSTest Project targeting .NET is not available from the project template

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mstest

In Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise I don't see Unit Test Project for .NET (eg. .Net Core) in the project template. Specifically, I am looking to create  MSTest projects targeting .NET 6 but all I see is Unit Test Project (.NET Framework) showing in the available options. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: Use the installer to check which features are currently installed. (at the bottom of your screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because the Visual Studio installer has some problems installing .net desktop development, please follow the steps below:

1. Please open the Visual Studio installation tool, find Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise and click Modify.
2. Find .net desktop development in Workloads to see if it is installed. Install it if it is not installed.
3. If the MSTest Project has been installed but still cannot be found, please use the Visual Studio installation tool to repair Visual Studio or uninstall .net desktop development and reinstall .net desktop development

[image]